# Wrapping a Dictionary<K,V> to make it observable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tree of model object which I am displaying in a TreeView using a hierarchical data template. Each model object is converted on the fly to a ViewModel object using a ValueConverter, but the Model's properties are still bound to for the child items in the hierarchical data template.

The problem I have is that the Model objects store their children in dictionaries, and it's specifically the values, rather than the keys that I'm interested in client side. The Dictionary is not Observable, so what I am looking for is - in an ideal world - a way to wrap the Dictionary (or perhaps more specifically the internal ValueCollection that the Dictionary uses on the "Values" property, in order to make it observable.

I've delved into the source of the Dictionary to see if there are any hidden hooks I could reflect, but I can't see anything.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Edit:

The behaviour I want is effectively this:

```
var nonObservable = new Dictionary<Guid, object>();

var observableDictionary = new ObservableDictionary<Guid, object>(nonObservable);
observableDictionary.CollectionChanged += //Some event handler

nonObservable.Add(Guid.NewGuid, new object());
```

When I add objects to the non-observable Dictionary, I want a collection changed event on the wrapper to fire. This will probably require some deep reflecting. It's a hacky approach that I would rather avoid, but I don't really like the alternatives either.

Comment: People have already made [ObservableDictionary](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx) classes which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks for the Link, but it's not suitable for my scenario, as I need to transparently wrap an existing dictionary, effectively "attaching" the observable behaviour.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @RBT Well that link I provided provides the override `new ObservableDictionary(existingDictionary)`... no good?

Comment: Have you looked in to policy injection?  Based upon what you wrote, it looks like it might be a viable solution.  Depending, of course, on your motivation to wire the whole thing up...

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface. Internally, you'd use a Dictionary, so your class would act as a proxy between the client and the real dictionary. However, you'd also be raising events, like this:

```
public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
  private IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary = //...
  public event EventHandler<DictionaryChangedArgs> OnAdded;

  public ObservableDictionary()
  {
    _dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
  }    

  //wrap an existing dictionary
  public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<Tkey, TValue> dictionary)
  {
    _dictionary = dictionary;
  }   

  public void Add(TKey key, TValue val) {
    _dictionary.Add(key, value);

    if(OnAdded != null)
      OnAdded(new DictionaryChangedArgs(key, value));    
  }

}
```

**Edit**

Updated the code to reflect your requirement: "wrap an existing dictionary".
The idea seems to be similar to the one presented on dav_i's link.

Comment: I've added code showing the problem behaviour I'm trying to get. It's not as straight forward as clients will continue to use the non observable dictionary.

Comment: @dcastro, the OP needs to intercept calls to the orignal dictionary

Comment: I don't think you can do that even with reflection. The alternative to using the Observable pattern here, is to constantly poll the dictionary for changes - which is expensive and a possible source of problems.

Comment: Are you sure you can't make your code's client use the observable dictionary instead? If he's programming against the IDictionary interface, you could swap their dictionary with yours.

Comment: You can do that with policy injection, hence my original comment.  In your answer, the clients have to know to call the observable class and not the original class.

Comment: They do not _have_ to know - if you're given an instance of `IDictionary` by reference, you could swap it. We're using the decorator pattern here - clients would have no idea that the dictionary has been decorated. It all depends on what the code looks like. I had never heard about policy injection, so your solution may well be more satisfying than a decorator here ;)